# How to share .jar files between Java Applications

Tags: java, jar

We have a suit of application which have some common .Jar files. While installing each app these files are copied to each application's folder. This results in wastage of storage space and also it is tedious to keep the files in sync. Does java provide any way to share .jars? Like in windows we can copy .dll file in \windows\system32 and it is available to all apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two apps are on the same machine, you can put/deploy the jars in one folder.
Then both apps can pick/load the jars at runtime from that shared folder. This is doable.

Say your folder is:
`/some/folder/`

And the jars there are
`a.jar`
`b.jar`
`c.jar`

Then just add

`/some/folder/a.jar`
`/some/folder/b.jar`
`/some/folder/c.jar`

to the classpaths of both apps (in the two apps' startup scripts).

*But there's no one single pre-defined place on OS level

to put those into (like `\Windows\System32` let's say)

so that all Java apps on that machine pick their jars from

there. And I find this a very good thing. So things are not

quite the same as with DLLs (the example you give).*

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options:

1. You can use something like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), which will manage the JAR files for you.
2. You can create a library folder and reference this to the projects you've got.
3. If you're using Eclipse, you can create shared user libraries (read more [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/ide/0321288157/java-project-configuration/ch06lev1sec2)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think OP is asking about runtime, not about dev/compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 version 40 application class data sharing has been implemented, see

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/310

It took a little figuring out but I have 4 JVMs running using shared classes. The following script was used to set up and test sharing and with a little modification could be used elsewhere:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Libraries to load
LIBS1="./lib/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:\
./lib/jetty-server-9.2.18.v20160721.jar:./lib/jetty-util-9.2.18.v20160721.jar:./lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar:./lib/jetty-http-9.2.18.v20160721.jar:./lib/jetty-io-9.2.18.v20160721.jar:\
./lib/derby.jar:\
./lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:"
LIBS2=":./lib/GTFS.jar"

# Uncomment these lines for the first phase where you are determining the classes to archive. During this phase aim to get as many classes loaded as possible
# which means loading a schedule and retrieving the stop list and next vehicle information
#
#APPCDS="-Xshare:off -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UseAppCDS -XX:DumpLoadedClassList=../GtfsAppCds.lst"
#java -Xmx512m $APPCDS -Dderby.system.home=database -classpath $LIBS1$LIBS2 com.transitrtd.GtfsOperatorManager

# Uncomment these lines when the class list is created and run to create the shared archive. Classes marked as unverifiable will need to be removed from the
# archived class list in GtfsAppCds.lst and the lines below run again. LIBS2 above contains jars which are left out of the archive. These are jars which change
# frequently and would therefore cause the archive to be frequently rebuilt.
#                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#APPCDS="-Xshare:dump -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UseAppCDS -XX:SharedClassListFile=../GtfsAppCds.lst -XX:SharedArchiveFile=../GtfsAppCds.jsa"
#java -Xmx512m $APPCDS -classpath $LIBS1

# Uncomment these lines when wishing to verify the application is using the shared archive.
#
#APPCDS="-Xshare:on -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UseAppCDS -XX:SharedArchiveFile=../GtfsAppCds.jsa -verbose:class"
#java -Xmx512m $APPCDS -Dderby.system.home=database -classpath $LIBS1$LIBS2 com.transitrtd.GtfsOperatorManager
```

Note that the shared archive file (i.e.the jsa file) is architecture dependent and will need to be built on each target platform type.

Also if a jar uses sealed packages a security exception is thrown, see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html

for information on sealed packages. This was the case above with *derby.jar* but the problem could be solved by unpacking the jar file, replacing *Sealed:true* with *Sealed:false* in the manifest and repacking it.

jars built with older versions of java cannot be used in a shared archive, in the case above the derby version needed to be upgraded from 10.10 to 10.14 to benefit.